# flycheck: undefined name 'xrange'

Tags: python, emacs, flake8, flycheck

I am running `emacs24` and I'm new to emacs. I have some code in Python 2.7 that I am checking with `flycheck`.
When I check the syntax, I get:

```
error F821 undefined name 'xrange' (python-flake8)
```

I understand that `xrange` is not in Python3, but here I'm on Python 2.7. I guess it's configured to run on Python 3, since also `raw_input` yields the same error.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Flycheck does not care about the difference between Python 2 and Python 3.  It runs the first `flake8` executable it finds in `exec-path`, and in your case, that's apparently a flake8 installed for Python 3.

You need to install flake8 for Python 2 and point Flycheck to that executable, either by putting the target directory in `exec-path` or with `M-x flycheck-set-checker-executable`.

I recommend to use a dedicated Python 2 virtualenv for your project and make Emacs and set `python-shell-virtualenv-root` to that directory in Python buffers (for instance with [Directory Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html)).  Then you can point `exec-path` to that virtualenv.  With a little [custom Emacs Lisp](https://github.com/lunaryorn/.emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/flycheck-virtualenv.el) you can even automate that.

Answer (score 0):

I were struggling with same problem, and can recommend use my solution for that: https://github.com/rmuslimov/flycheck-local-flake8. It's trivial - and it will force **flycheck** use proper **flake8** executable from your virtualenv.

I'd recommend add `setup.cfg` to each python project you work on. Flake8 has some environment variables which may be defined there. For example here is mine:

```
[metadata]
name=fastttrace
version=release.5.9.0

[flake8]
exclude = tests/*, migrations/*
ignore = D100,D101,D102,D103,D205,D400,E731
import-order-style = google
max-complexity = 15
```

It allows you have separate flake8 rules per project and store them in repo, which is convenient way to share with other devs.